# Unable to assign value to an array with for loop Verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog

I need to make an n-bit adder in verilog with the help of a 4 bit `carry_lookahead` module (the n that I mentioned will be a multiple of 4). I think I have figured out how to deal with the carries however I can't assign values to the sums (which is the `s[n-1:0]` array). I keep getting the errors below:

```
in line 22: near "[": syntax error, unexpected '['
in line 22:(vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 's'. Is there a missing '::'?
```

This is the `carry_lookahead` module which works fine:

```
module cla4(a,b,cin,cout);
parameter n=4;
genvar i;
input cin;
input [3:0]a,b;
wire [3:0]c;
output  cout;

assign g0=(a[0]&b[0]);
assign p0=((a[0]^b[0])&cin);
assign c[0]=(g0|p0);

assign g1=(a[1]&b[1]);
assign p1=((a[1]^b[1])&c[0]);
assign c[1]=(g1|p1);

assign g2=(a[2]&b[2]);
assign p2=((a[2]^b[2])&c[1]);
assign c[2]=(g2|p2);

assign g3=(a[3]&b[3]);
assign p3=((a[3]^b[3])&c[2]);
assign cout=(g3|p3);


endmodule
```

And the main program:

```
module n_bits_adder (a,b,cin,cout,s);
genvar i,k;
parameter n=8;
input cin;
input [n-1:0]a,b;
output reg [n-1:0]s;
output cout;
reg [n:0]c;


for(i=0;i<n/4;i=i+1)
begin
cla4 U1(.a0(a[i]),.a1(a[i+1]),.a2(a[i+2]),.a3(a[i+3]),.b0(b[i]),.b1(b[i+1]),.b2(b[i+2]),.b3(b[i+3]),.cin(c[i]),.cout(c[i+1]));
assign cin=c[0];
assign cout=c[i+1];
end

for(k=0;k<n;k=k+1)
begin
case({a[k],b[k],c[k]}) //i check the inputs for each adder and assign the 
                              correct value to the sum below

3'b000: s[k]=1'b0;
3'b001: s[k]=1'b1;
3'b010: s[k]=1'b1;
3'b011: s[k]=1'b0;
3'b100: s[k]=1'b1;
3'b101: s[k]=1'b0;
3'b110: s[k]=1'b0;
3'b111: s[k]=1'b1;
end
endmodule
```

Why won't it let me assign values to `s`?

Answer (score 0):

You use generate 'for' and 'case' statements. The usage of the `case` as a generate statement is incorrect in your examples.

1) the selection condition must be one which can be resolved at generate time. So, you cannot use any non-constant variables, though you concatenated inputs a, b and c there. Compiler will not be able to resolve this generate 'case' statement.

```
 case({a[k],b[k],c[k]}) //i check the inputs for each adder and assign the 
                         correct value to the sum below
```

2) the actions in the case statement must be legal module-level statements. In your example they are

```
3'b000: s[k]=1'b0; << this is an illegal statement
```

perhaps the following would do `3'b000: always @* s[k]=1'b0;`, however since you did not have that `always` there, compiler correctly detected the syntax error.

Judging by your code, I guess that you just missed an always statement surrounding the 'case'. Something like the following should work:

```
for(k=0;k<n;k=k+1)
begin: case_loop
    always @* begin // << you need this
        case({a[k],b[k],c[k]}) //i check the inputs for each adder and assign the 
                          correct value to the sum below

        3'b000: s[k]=1'b0;
        3'b001: s[k]=1'b1;
        ...

    end
  end
```